# Changing dockpanels based on selection of listbox item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a listbox in column=0 of a grid, a splitter and the whole column=1 of the grid is for me to fill up with Textboxes to accept various values. But the textboxes would differ based on the listbox item I selected. Some how I figured it can be achieved with DataTemplate (or ContentTmplate ??). How do you achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

See DataTemplateSelector feature, you have to specify ContentTemplateSelector of ContentControl to achieve this. Also you have to define one DataTemplate per textbox type and in DataTemplateSelector return right textbox template depends on passed in item. Do search on  SO and yo will find a lot of examples.